# How to make smart components in React even more smarter by making it more flexible rendering other dump components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-state-management

I currently have one issue with container approach when it comes to rendering dump components.

Let's assume I have a **ProductContainer** as bellow:

```
class ProductContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { products: [] };
    }

    getAll(){
      // get all products from store
    }

    addNew(){
      // store the product to the store
    }

     render() {
      return (
        <ListProductComponent products={this.state.products}>
        <AddProductComponent/>
      )
     }
}
```

I could use redux for managing the store, but in this case I just want to keep it as simple as possible.

Then I have two more dump components as **ListProductComponent** and **AddProductComponent**.

```
const ListProductComponent = (props) => {
    return (
       <h2>Print out products from {props.products}</h2>
    );
};

const AddProductComponent = (props) => {
    return (
       <h2>AddProductComponent</h2>
    );
};
```

So far, so smart and so dump, but the issue is here when it comes to smart rendering, how can I make the smart component render only **ListProductComponent** for example, or only **AddProductComponent** separately.

Currently I have both components showing up on my render function from the container, I would actually like to keep the container to do the CRUD operation for the Product entity and then use the same component for either listing products, adding new product in all other dump components.

With current implementation I can not achieve this, I am forced to have bothe listing and adding new product to the same view.

Some folks suggest having ListProductContainer and addProductContainer separately handling crud operations, but isnt this way too much of seperation? I actually would like to keep crud in one smart component.

How can I achieve this having more flexible rendering for the very smart component.

UPDATE:
Probably I would want to have on container render part smth like this, but I am not sure if smth like this would work.

```
function renderComponent(Component) {
         return <Component />;
}
```

and then call this renderComponent inside render() on container, but then how do I pass the state/store or other attributes to the dump component?

Keeping in consideration that I would be able to do the same thing like this:

```
<ListProductComponent products={products} fetchProducts={this.getAll}/>
```

being able to pass the state and call parent/container methods.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to conditionally render a component? You will need to use a ternary operator in your render method to do so.

For example:

```
class ProductContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { products: [] };
  }

  getAll(){
    // get all products from store
  }

  addNew(){
    // store the product to the store
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {
        this.state.products.length ? 
          <ListProductComponent products={this.state.products}>
        :
          <AddProductComponent/>
      }
    ) 
  }
}
```

You will also need to use `this.setState({ products: [ // products object ] })` after a product is been added so React re-renders the component and shows the correct data.

You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: You got it right that I want to conditionally render the dump components, but I am not so sure if this is the correct approach, how about if I have about 5 dump components separately,  let say, list, add, delete, update, filterByStatus etc...  What would be the logic of rendering?

Comment: I found this article: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/react-js-presentational-container-components, which does actually what I am looking for, but I am just not so sure about this how do I pass the props to the dump components using this technique and call containers methods from the dump cmp.

Comment: @Mizlul You define methods in the props of the presentational component which you populate in the render method of the container component.

Comment: @Mizlul if you have a conditional that is more than just an `if/else`. You can use a method like `renderComponent` that returns a `JSX`. Either through many `if` statements or a `switch/case`. I recommend the latter.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic I am not sure if I understand what you mean, can u show some example?

Comment: @Baruch renderComponent() sounds better, propably I will wrap the container component into a function with an Component argument and in render return component arg.

Comment: I achieved what I wanted using https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html